# Pre Requisite for bootcamp, Quardratic Equation, I am stuck

Tags: r, testing, quadratic

Just going to link the question; I have no other info to go off of; and I am very confused, Would love a solution; but also if you could explain the how and why, that would be extremely helpful TYIA
[PROBLEM FROM TEST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arT8O.png)

Comment: For the equation `2x^2 -x - 4 = 0` , a=2, b=-1, and c=-4. Just plug these values into the formula they provide.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it doesn't seem to be about programming

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function to solve the quadratic equation , which takes the coefficient of the equation a, b , c and return the roots

```
fn <- function(a , b , c){
    root1 <- (-b + sqrt(b^2 - 4*a*c)) / (2*a)
    root2 <- (-b - sqrt(b^2 - 4*a*c)) / (2*a)
    round(c(root1 , root2) , digits = 3)
}
```

then apply it to your question as follows

```
fn(2,-1,-4)

[1]  1.686 -1.186
```